# Floating Mosaic

Tags: modeling

Hope someone can help here.
I'm trying to create a mosaic using an .SVG file and then animate it with a wave effect so that it looks like tiles floating on water with the shape of the SVG.

The only thing that came to mind was to convert the SVG file from curves to mesh, subdivide it and then turn on instancing by vertices using a brick model so that every vert of the svg would have a brick in it's place. It worked to some extent but it is really messy.

Do have any other workflow to suggest in order to achieve this effect?

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

Thanks a bunch!!

Kris

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you illustrate what you want? Some sample image or drawing? (because from what you say so far... several possible things can come in mind).

Comment: Hi no sorry I don't have a specific drawing. Let's say the thing I need to know is how to fill an SVG image with bricks. Do you think that would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if there is a reason you are doing this with the svg as objects and not using an image map and alpha on a subdivided plane and cloth or displacement or something along those lines... basically a flag thats parallel to the ground.